# How to get exact camera view?

Tags: rendering, objects, 3d-view, camera, eevee-render-engine

I'm currently a beginner when it comes to 3D modelling but doing okay so far. I'm struggling a bit when it comes to the final renders of my scene, specifically on the camera view I want. Sometimes its to zoomed in and sometimes to zoomed out that it's gone out of the environment of the blender. I realized the settings for the camera on blender are for actual cameras / photography and I'm no expert on that too. A tip on how to control them precisely would be nice. Thank you.

Comment: Press number pad '0' to go into camera view.

Answer (score 2):

Go into camera view (<kbd>Numpad 0</kbd>) and use **Lock Camera to View**.

[image]

Then, navigate as you would normally do in the 3d viewport using the mouse or the keyboard.

<kbd>Numpad 4</kbd> and <kbd>Numpad 6</kbd> will rotate left right.

<kbd>Numpad 8</kbd> and <kbd>Numpad 2</kbd> will rotate up and down

<kbd>Numpad +</kbd> and <kbd>Numpad -</kbd> willmove the camera forward and back

[image]

Or Use Fly/Walk mode:

https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/3dview/navigate/walk_fly.html?highlight=walk%20mode